# Download multiple files using CXF JAX-RS

Tags: java, cxf, jax-rs

I have a requirement where I want to pass multiple thumbnails to UI (`javascript`) as the response of `GET` Request.
Each thumbnail is a separate file, so essentially I want to pass multiple files.
Is downloading multiple files even a sane idea? If yes, how can we do using **CXF JAX-RS** ? 
I tried below code which is not working.

```
@GET
@Path("/streamThumbnails")
@Produces("multipart/mixed")
   public MultipartBody getBooks2() {
      List<Attachment> atts = new LinkedList<Attachment>();
      File thumbnail1 = new File("//D:/pdf2.pdf");
      File thumbnail2 = new File("//D:/pdf3.pdf");
      atts.add(new Attachment("thumbnail1", "application/pdf",thumbnail1));
      atts.add(new Attachment("thumbnail2", "application/pdf",thumbnail2));
      return new MultipartBody(atts, true);  
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are talking about thumbnails I guess you want to download images, and not PDFs as in your example. Why not to stripe them together into a single image and have the client use them as [CSS sprites](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprite_%28computer_graphics%29#Sprites_by_CSS)?

Comment: Actually later I want to do the same thing with PDF as well.So looking for a common solution.

Comment: I have a feeling that browsers will block the download of multiple times

Comment: i have the same feeling, not sure though. I think i'll have to Zip the files and proceed.

Comment: For PDFs I agree (and this is the Gmail and Google drive solution for downloading multiple files). For thumbnail images I stand by my answer